# Radar animation android

Tags: android, animation

So here is the thing. I am monitoring certain distances, and i would like to display them in a radar animation. The base radar image would be something [like this (not exactly)](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=radar&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=zJkkncIJrImHhM%253A%253BXwxQAE9-9ee0lM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.primicias.com.do%25252Findex.php%25252Fopinion%25252F4124-que-pasa-con-los-equipos-de-radar-comprados-por-rd-a-israel&source=iu&usg=__yCeA52A0KLE528jH4pTUmAiY-NE%3D&sa=X&ei=eoriU8H-N-_msASM3oGACA&ved=0CEcQ9QEwBg&biw=1360&bih=705#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=zJkkncIJrImHhM%253A%3BXwxQAE9-9ee0lM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.primicias.com.do%252Fimages%252Fstories%252Fdemo%252FColumnistas%252Fradar.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.primicias.com.do%252Findex.php%252Fopinion%252F4124-que-pasa-con-los-equipos-de-radar-comprados-por-rd-a-israel%3B1200%3B1200)

where every circle  means a distance range. The idea is that the dot moves towards the circles as the distance changes. My initial approach was to make different images of the same radar with the dot on each circle and simply switch them according the distance. But then i wonder if there any chance(performant, and that works fine on different resolutions) to have one base image of the radar and simply move the dot. I hope I am being clear and if anyone has an idea i would be very thankful

I am not posting any code, cause i need the idea, then ill struggle with  the implementation

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried these examples?

https://github.com/jfabrix101/RadarCustomVIew

https://github.com/gpfduoduo/RadarScanView

i.e

Radar.java

```
public class RadarView extends View {

    private final String LOG = "RadarView";
    private final int POINT_ARRAY_SIZE = 25;

    private int fps = 100;
    private boolean showCircles = true;

    float alpha = 0;
    Point latestPoint[] = new Point[POINT_ARRAY_SIZE];
    Paint latestPaint[] = new Paint[POINT_ARRAY_SIZE];

    public RadarView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RadarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RadarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        Paint localPaint = new Paint();
        localPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        localPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        localPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        localPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0F);
        localPaint.setAlpha(0);

        int alpha_step = 255 / POINT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        for (int i=0; i < latestPaint.length; i++) {
            latestPaint[i] = new Paint(localPaint);
            latestPaint[i].setAlpha(255 - (i* alpha_step));
        }
    }


        android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        Runnable mTick = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000 / fps);
        }
        };


    public void startAnimation() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
        mHandler.post(mTick);
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
    }

    public void setFrameRate(int fps) { this.fps = fps; }
    public int getFrameRate() { return this.fps; };

    public void setShowCircles(boolean showCircles) { this.showCircles =     showCircles; }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int r = Math.min(width, height);


        //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), localPaint);

        int i = r / 2;
        int j = i - 1;
        Paint localPaint = latestPaint[0]; // GREEN

        if (showCircles) {
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j * 3 / 4, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j >> 1, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j >> 2, localPaint);
        }

        alpha -= 0.5;
        if (alpha < -360) alpha = 0;
        double angle = Math.toRadians(alpha);
        int offsetX =  (int) (i + (float)(i * Math.cos(angle)));
        int offsetY = (int) (i - (float)(i * Math.sin(angle)));

        latestPoint[0]= new Point(offsetX, offsetY);

        for (int x=POINT_ARRAY_SIZE-1; x > 0; x--) {
            latestPoint[x] = latestPoint[x-1];
        }



        int lines = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < POINT_ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
            Point point = latestPoint[x];
            if (point != null) {
                canvas.drawLine(i, i, point.x, point.y, latestPaint[x]);
            }
        }


        lines = 0;
        for (Point p : latestPoint) if (p != null) lines++;

        boolean debug = false;
        if (debug) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" >> ");
            for (Point p : latestPoint) {
                if (p != null) sb.append(" (" + p.x + "x" + p.y + ")");
            }

            Log.d(LOG, sb.toString());
            //  " - R:" + r + ", i=" + i +
            //  " - Size: " + width + "x" + height +
            //  " - Angle: " + angle +
            //  " - Offset: " + offsetX + "," + offsetY);
        }

    }

}
```

in your activity.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start"
    android:onClick="startAniamtion"/>

<frusso.radartest.RadarView
    android:id="@+id/radarView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="stop"
    android:onClick="stopAnimation"/>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadarView mRadarView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRadarView = (RadarView) findViewById(R.id.radarView);
        mRadarView.setShowCircles(true);
    }


    public void stopAnimation(View view) {
        if (mRadarView != null) mRadarView.stopAnimation();
    }

    public void startAnimation(View view) {
        if (mRadarView != null) mRadarView.startAnimation();
    }
}
```

Hope this will guide you for your requirement.

Comment: Your above code is running super. How to place Geo-location points in above code.

Comment: you can use

 /*
            to draw horizontal line
             */
            canvas.drawLine(i-r, j,i+r , j, localPaint);

            /*
            to draw vertical line
             */
            canvas.drawLine(i, j-r,i , j+r, localPaint);
to get lines in circle

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have one static image of the radar and another of the dot (if you wanted a custom one).  I'd have 2 main threads, the game loop and one that moves the dot on your radar image based on your position.

Comment: I thought of that, but how will i manage dot posicion? dp? would that work on any resolution or size screen?

Comment: You would need multiple radar/ dot images for different resolutions (i.e. having a bigger radar on tablets than on smartphones).  Managing dot position depends on the implementation of your app.  Using global variables for the dot position, if you map (x,y) coordinates and map your character as the origin and the object that is coming in range to its (x,y) distance from origin you could then scale those coordinates and map that on your radar.

Answer (score 0):

"I am monitoring certain distances" ~ What does that mean?

To make a radar create a class that extends ImageView.  Override onDraw(Canvas canvas) and set the image resource to a radar background.

```
 @Override
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     //draw background
     super.onDraw(canvas);

     for(PointF p : points)
     {
         //draw each point as an image.  Maybe, translate by width/2 and height/2
     }
 }
```

Comment: So im using a translate animation to set the dot where i want it. I figure given its "relative_to_parent" capability, that it would work as i intended to. The thing is i am not sure i understood the animation  perfectly, if i set fromYValue to "relative_to_parent" and then i set and 0,8 shouldn't my animation end at my parent 80 % width?