# How to make animation like radar signal in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have an app in which I have to make an animation similar to that of a radar signal. But I am not quite sure of how to accomplish this. Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

#### Example of image like animation

[image: animation]

Comment: Please try to add specific technical detail info. No one knows where you want to make or how you want to create animation.

Comment: Your question seems a bit too broad so try referring to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm). It has a pretty detailed explanation on how to create basic animations in android. Then provide your workings if you have any further issues

Answer (score 4):

The answer is already given here at this so post [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33013216/4079010) given by **Ajay Pandya**

You can use some below libraries

https://github.com/jfabrix101/RadarCustomVIew

https://github.com/gpfduoduo/RadarScanView

i.e

Radar.java

```
public class RadarView extends View {

    private final String LOG = "RadarView";
    private final int POINT_ARRAY_SIZE = 25;

    private int fps = 100;
    private boolean showCircles = true;

    float alpha = 0;
    Point latestPoint[] = new Point[POINT_ARRAY_SIZE];
    Paint latestPaint[] = new Paint[POINT_ARRAY_SIZE];

    public RadarView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RadarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RadarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        Paint localPaint = new Paint();
        localPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        localPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        localPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        localPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0F);
        localPaint.setAlpha(0);

        int alpha_step = 255 / POINT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        for (int i=0; i < latestPaint.length; i++) {
            latestPaint[i] = new Paint(localPaint);
            latestPaint[i].setAlpha(255 - (i* alpha_step));
        }
    }


        android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        Runnable mTick = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000 / fps);
        }
        };


    public void startAnimation() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
        mHandler.post(mTick);
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
    }

    public void setFrameRate(int fps) { this.fps = fps; }
    public int getFrameRate() { return this.fps; };

    public void setShowCircles(boolean showCircles) { this.showCircles =     showCircles; }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int r = Math.min(width, height);


        //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), localPaint);

        int i = r / 2;
        int j = i - 1;
        Paint localPaint = latestPaint[0]; // GREEN

        if (showCircles) {
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j * 3 / 4, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j >> 1, localPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(i, i, j >> 2, localPaint);
        }

        alpha -= 0.5;
        if (alpha < -360) alpha = 0;
        double angle = Math.toRadians(alpha);
        int offsetX =  (int) (i + (float)(i * Math.cos(angle)));
        int offsetY = (int) (i - (float)(i * Math.sin(angle)));

        latestPoint[0]= new Point(offsetX, offsetY);

        for (int x=POINT_ARRAY_SIZE-1; x > 0; x--) {
            latestPoint[x] = latestPoint[x-1];
        }



        int lines = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < POINT_ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
            Point point = latestPoint[x];
            if (point != null) {
                canvas.drawLine(i, i, point.x, point.y, latestPaint[x]);
            }
        }


        lines = 0;
        for (Point p : latestPoint) if (p != null) lines++;

        boolean debug = false;
        if (debug) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" >> ");
            for (Point p : latestPoint) {
                if (p != null) sb.append(" (" + p.x + "x" + p.y + ")");
            }

            Log.d(LOG, sb.toString());
            //  " - R:" + r + ", i=" + i +
            //  " - Size: " + width + "x" + height +
            //  " - Angle: " + angle +
            //  " - Offset: " + offsetX + "," + offsetY);
        }

    }

}
```

in your activity.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start"
    android:onClick="startAniamtion"/>

<frusso.radartest.RadarView
    android:id="@+id/radarView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="stop"
    android:onClick="stopAnimation"/>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadarView mRadarView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRadarView = (RadarView) findViewById(R.id.radarView);
        mRadarView.setShowCircles(true);
    }


    public void stopAnimation(View view) {
        if (mRadarView != null) mRadarView.stopAnimation();
    }

    public void startAnimation(View view) {
        if (mRadarView != null) mRadarView.startAnimation();
    }
}
```