# How do create scanview like this image?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How do I create scan view like this image in android application, Please give some ideas

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given here at this so post see here given by Ajay Pandya

[Radar animation android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169231/radar-animation-android/33013216#33013216)